# Google Web Speech API Limits

Tags: speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I am developing a web application which gets input from user. I will be using Google Web Speech API like dictation.io. I wonder, what is the limit and how is it calculated? For example for dictation.io it can be used all over the world. What is the limit for that? Individual user base limit or application base limit? Because I am able to talk 20-30 minutes without any problem with dictation.io.

BTW, I am not talking about Cloud Speech API, since my application is web based I don't need them (AFAIK).

Thanks.